# Scatter plot with different colors and markers from wide formatted data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a set of data with different variables and I want to plot `"Concentration at 10℃"` against `"Mean pH at 10"`, `"concentration at 17.5C"` against `"Mean pH at 17.5"` and `"concentration at 25C"` against `"Mean pH at 25"` all in same graph.

[image: test data]

```py
data = {'sample': ['24h', '1W', '2W', '3W', '5W'],
        'Concentration at 10°C': [4.36, 4.84, 7.20, 4.14, 1.09], 'Mean pH 10': [8.2, 7.9, 8.1, 8.3, 8.2],
        'concentration at 17.5°C': [4.4, 5.85, 5.35, 3.98, 1], 'Mean pH 17.5': [8.15, 8.2, 8.35, 8.4, 8.45],
        'concentration at 25°C': [3.27, 4.31, 5.74, 4.18, 2.4], 'Mean pH 25': [8.4, 8.25, 8.2, 8.15, 8.35]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  sample  Concentration at 10°C  Mean pH 10  concentration at 17.5°C  Mean pH 17.5  concentration at 25°C  Mean pH 25
0    24h                   4.36         8.2                     4.40          8.15                   3.27        8.40
1     1W                   4.84         7.9                     5.85          8.20                   4.31        8.25
2     2W                   7.20         8.1                     5.35          8.35                   5.74        8.20
3     3W                   4.14         8.3                     3.98          8.40                   4.18        8.15
4     5W                   1.09         8.2                     1.00          8.45                   2.40        8.35
```

I have 15 samples, each sample has 2 features (a time point: e.g. 24h, and a temperature: e.g. 10C), I want to plot all my data together but in a way that each time point has a specific marker (e.g. all 24h represented by square) and each temperature also represented by a color (e.g. 10C by blue), this way when a reader looks at my figure and for instance sees a blue square, they know what that sample is,

I've managed to plot all my data in one sample, but I am lost on how to change the marker and color of different samples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load Data
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\fatemeha\Desktop\MiCoDy\WP1-spring-LR-April2021.xlsx', sheet_name=7)
print(df)

df.plot.scatter(x=['Mean concentration at 10℃','Mean concentration at 17.5C', 'Mean concentration at 25C'], y=["Mean pH at 10", "Mean pH at 17.5", "Mean pH at 25"],
        rot=0, color=["blue"] , xlabel='.', ylabel=".", marker=4,
        title="pH change in Lake Rot Mesocosms in Spring 2021")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The easiest way will be to reshape and clean the dataframe into a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) (long) form.

  - Unfortunately, some data (temperature) has been encoded into the column names. **This is a bad practice**, don't do it.
  - [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) can be used to convert the dataframe to a tidy format, which will also extract the temperatures encoded in the column names.

    - `suffix='(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')` is required to extract the `int` and `float` types from the column names, otherwise `suffix='.+'` will get all characters after the specified `sep` character.
    - The column name suffix must be in a standard form, which is extracted based on the regular expression. If the column name formats are not the same, they must be fixed before using `.wide_to_long`. The column names can be fixed by using [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) or [`.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)
    - All `stubnames` must also be standardized.
- Once the dataframe is converted to a tidy format, it can be easily plotted with [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), which is a high-level API for `matplotlib`

  - This can also be done using [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) with `kind='scatter'`
- Test with `pandas 1.3.1`, `seaborn 0.11.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# using the dataframe from the OP

# remove °C so column suffixes will have a standard form
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('°C', '').str.replace('concen', 'Concen')

# convert the dataframe to a tidy format
dfl = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Concentration at', 'Mean pH'], j='°C', sep=' ', i='sample', suffix='.+').reset_index()

# rename a columns
dfl.rename({'Concentration at': 'Mean Concentration'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# display(dfl.head())
  sample    °C  Mean Concentration  Mean pH
0    24h  10.0                4.36      8.2
1     1W  10.0                4.84      7.9
2     2W  10.0                7.20      8.1
3     3W  10.0                4.14      8.3
4     5W  10.0                1.09      8.2

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 7))
p = sns.scatterplot(data=dfl, x='Mean Concentration', y='Mean pH', hue='°C', style='sample', palette='tab10', ax=ax, s=50)
p.set(title='Measurement Data')
_ = p.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]